# Edit Row + Add Row, facing issues in inline editing JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am not looking for code, but idea. I have inline add - edit feature in jqgrid. On clicking editrow, without saving or canceling, I am clicking addrow, the editedrow is not restoring. Addrow calls the jquery.jqgrid.js. So is there anyway to restore that easily or should I do it in the plugin only? Please assist. Thanks.

Comment: In general,while inline editing row,add row should be disabled, but if you are looking for add and edit at same time, use local storage to hold data until it is saved.or you can  use `reloadAfterSubmit` property to stop refreshing your grid..Hope that make sense!

Comment: Sorry, but you should describe more clear what you do and what is your question. The statement "On clicking editrow, without saving or canceling, I am clicking addrow, the editedrow is not restoring." is absolutely unclear. What you do? What you want to implement? Which version and fork of jqGrid you use? Do you edit local data or save the data on the server (`datatype`, `editurl`)

Comment: I am using latest version of free jqgrid. I use editurl. everything is url. I have edit button in rows and add button in footer. This is what I do, 1) I click on a edit button, the row becomes editable. 2)I click on add button, new row is added, however the edited row before has not restored. This is the issue I am facing. On clicking add button, I want the edited row to be restored.